# Second grass algorithm in QGIS modeler cannot use output from first algorithm

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'm using QGIS 3.0.0 and I've created a model to delineate a watershed. The model has 3 steps:

1. Merge 4 SRTM tiles
2. Run `r.watershed` on the merged tiles
3. Run `r.water.outlet` on the flow direction output from step 2. This part also uses a string input representing the outlet position (x,y)

The first 2 steps (merge and `r.watershed`) run fine. But `r.water.outlet` complains that it could not find the input raster (flow direction). I noticed that between the two GRASS algorithm, a new grass section is being initialized. Could this cause QGIS not to find the input raster?

Log from the model run can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/yTAqFyDm)

The model I'm using is represented bellow.
[image: Basin delineation model]

Comment: I was able to make it work if I removed the intermediary outputs. I was saving the flow direction prior to running `r.water.outlet`.

Comment: Since this looks like a problem regarding intermediary results from 'Processing Modeler' being saved, I'll open a new question specific about this