# Can I save intermediary results in QGIS Processing Modeler using GRASS algorithms?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I created a 'Processing Model' in QGIS 3.0 that uses two GRASS algorithms: `r.watershed` and `r.water.outlet`. I'm interested in the output from `r.water.outlet` but I noticed that if I try to save intermediary results from `r.watershed`, the model does not work.

Ex.: In the model bellow, if I try to save the flow direction output from `r.watershed`, things break. If I remove the intermediary file being saved, the output from `r.water.outlet` works.

[image]

This question is a follow-up of the following: [Second grass algorithm in QGIS modeler cannot use output from first algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277186/second-grass-algorithm-in-qgis-modeler-cannot-use-output-from-first-algorithm)